# Laravel - stripe-php Testing

Tags: laravel, testing

Hi trying to mock stripe in test cases, but couldnt achieve that.

Also i couldnt find any sample about test coverage.

I need to mock;

```
new StripeClient
```

and

```
paymentIntents->create
```

etc. methods.

How to handle this?

How can I mock stripe for my test coverage?

Comment: why mock the classes, use sandbox mode for your integration tests

Comment: @N69S its my feature tests. i can not use sandbox mode, it'll be worked million times everytime. I should mock it.

Answer (score 1):

When working with external dependencies, it's always a good idea to wrap them in a class specific to your application that use an interface. This allows two things:

1. Your application becomes decouple from the dependency. If you wish to change it to something else, you don't have to rewrite the app, you simply update the wrapper around the dependency. As long as it respect the interface, your app will still work properly.
2. It allows you to mock this dependency. Your app doesn't have to know which payment provider it uses, it only needs to know there a way to process payment.

With that in mind, you could create an interface  `PaymentProcessingClient` that exposes only the methods your app are going to need. For example, "processPayment" and "retrieveCustomerId".

Now, you can create a custom class `StripePaymentProcessingClient`, which implements the `PaymentProcessingClient` interface, and call the StripeClient for each required functions.

```php
interface PaymentProcessingClient {
  public function processPayment(): void;
  
  public function retrieveCustomerId(): string;
}

class StripePaymentProcessingClient implements PaymentProcessingClient {
  private StripeClient $stripeClient;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->stripeClient = new StripeClient();
  }

  public function processPayment(): void {
    $this->stripeClient->/* ... */
  }
  
  public function retrieveCustomerId(): string {
    return $this->stripeClient->/* ... */
  }
}
```

Now, in the part of your app that require the Stripe client, you need to use dependency injection to import the `PaymentProcessingClient` interface. This will let you decouple the part of your app that needs payment processing from the payment processing client. This principle is known as the [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).

For example, rather than import `StripePaymentProcessingClient` or `StripeClient`, in your controller, you import `PaymentProcessingClient`.

```php
class PaymentController {

  public PaymentProcessingClient $paymentClient

  public function __construct(PaymentProcessingClient $injectedPaymentClient) {
    $this->paymentClient = $injectedPaymentClient;
  }
}
```

Lastly, you have to let laravel know what concrete class to load when importing the interface. For that, you can call the `bind` method, in the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider`.

```php
class AppServiceProvider {
  public function boot() {
    // whenever I require PaymentProcessingClient, please give me StripePaymentProcessingClient
    $this->app->bind(PaymentProcessingClient::class, StripePaymentProcessingClient::class);
  }
}
```

If you ever needs to change payment provider, simply create a new custom class that implements the `PaymentProcessingClient` and change the binding.

Now, with all of that, you still can't mock the `StripeClient` directly. However, since your app now depends on `PaymentProcessingClient` rather than `StripeClient`, you can mock `PaymentProcessingClient`.

```php
class PaymentControllerTest extends TestCase {
  public function test_it_should_process_payment() {
    // given a mock of the PaymentProcessingClient
    $this->instance(PaymentProcessingClient::class, function(MockInterface $mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('processPayment');
        
        return $mock;
    });

    // you now have a mocked StripeClient.
  }
}
```

As a final note, I would highly recommand reading the [Clean Architecture](https://www.amazon.ca/Clean-Architecture-Craftsmans-Software-Structure/dp/0134494164) book by uncle bob. It details what are the SOLID principles and how to use them to build highly maintainable and scalable applications.